# How can we identify an inactive user in Chat room

Tags: support, chat

As soon as I join some chat room my profile picture gets included in the side bar and also displays the number of users available in the room at that point of time .

- How can I or any other user know which user is inactive so that
  he/she doesn't waste time for expecting  an answer as there is no person active?
- Shouldn't it be there an inactive icon to distinguish no of users
  available from an inactive user.
- Well I am not forcing but just suggesting it if no then you can explain
  I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sidebar shows those users that are still in the room.

If the user's profile picture is there but greyed out/dimmed then it means that the user is still in the room, but inactive.

Comment: Which usually means that he left a tab open but not visiting it.